# -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

When running the below code, the `[dict setValue:@"null" forKey:@"name"];` keeps crashing. I search on here and found other posts were caused by people not using `NSMutableDictionary`. However I am using this.

Why is it crashing on this line if `name` is `null`?

```
NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in [[json objectForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy]) {
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"name"] == [NSNull null]) {
        [dict setValue:@"null" forKey:@"name"];
    }
    [tempCustomers addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: maybe mutableCopy is not "deepMutableCopy", i mean, you just enumerate mutable object but objects in this collection are not mutable?

Comment: You're using a mutable dictionary of immutable objects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using this. I'm guessing this is what a **deepMutableCopy** is?

```
NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in [[json objectForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy]) {
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"name"] == [NSNull null]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        tempDict = [dict mutableCopy];

        [tempDict setValue:@"null" forKey:@"name"];
        [tempCustomers addObject:tempDict];
    } else {
        [tempCustomers addObject:dict];
    }
}
```

Comment: This approximates a deep mutable copy - basically, you need a mutable copy of `dict` as well, not just of the JSON object's data. Each dictionary you were attempting to modify was itself immutable, even though the original collection of dictionaries became mutable through your `mutableCopy`. (The phrase "deep copy" refers to a recursive copy of all contained data structures, not just the top level.)

Comment: Precisely. You get a mutable copy of your JSON data (which still has immutable dictionaries), then you make a mutable copy of each dictionary - this approximates a "deep mutable copy," even if it's not in a separate method.

Answer (score 2):

maybe mutableCopy is not "deepMutableCopy", i mean, you just enumerate mutable object but objects in this collection are not mutable (copy from my comment)

Answer (score 0):

Create new array `[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"data"]]` and use it in the for loop

but instead running on `[json objectForKey:@"data"]` replace it to the new array.
it should look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *search = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"data"]];
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in search)
{
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"name"] == [NSNull null])
    {
        [dict setValue:@"null" forKey:@"name"];
    }
    [tempCustomers addObject:dict];
}
```